# Не сохраняется значение в инспекторе EditorGUILayout.IntField

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

У меня есть ScriptableObject для создания уровней с кастомными полями и есть скрипт Editor где задаются кастомные поля в ассетах созданных через ScriptableObject.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

[CustomEditor(typeof(RulesetTemplate))]
public partial class RulesetTemplateEditor : Editor
{
    [SerializeField] public int levelIndex;
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        GemsRules();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        MainRules();
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        BonusRules();
        levelIndex = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Level Index", levelIndex);
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "3Match/Ruleset")]
public class RulesetTemplate : ScriptableObject {

    public Character player;
    public List<Character> enemies;
    public int levelIndex;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно присвоить значение levelIndex в инспекторе, но значение сбрасывается на 0 как только я переключаюсь на другой объект или на другое поле. Что я делаю не так?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[SerializeField] public int levelIndex;` в `Editor`? Это вам не `MonoBehaviour` или `ScriptableObject`, это инструкция к отрисовке.

Никакой связи между `levelIndex` в `RulesetTemplateEditor` и `levelIndex` в `RulesetTemplate` нет.

Вы можете получить данные о поле отрисовываемого объекта через `serializedObject.FindProperty();`.

Почитайте хотя бы базовую документацию для начала, там не так уж много букв.

[Custom Editors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) пример кода: `C# Example (LookAtPointEditor.cs)` (первый)

Comment: Спасибо. Скажи, пожалуйста, есть возможность показать на моем примере как это реализовать? Я что-то совсем поплыл.

Comment: В `OnEnable` мы находим поли и сохраняем в виде `SerializedProperty`, а в `OnInspectorGUI` отрисовываем так, как нам хочется или даже меняем. Какой именно момент в примере с `lookAtPoint` у вас вызывает вопросы?

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо! Вопросы вызывает моя невнимательность.